# REST post query to GO server from bash works but fails for Python

Tags: python, json, curl, go, marshalling

I have `go server` that unmarshals the `json` it receives it.
It works when I do it using the `curl` but fails in case of `python`.

Go server Unmarshal code:

```
type Data struct {
    Namespace   string `json:"namespace"`
    ContainerId string `json:"containerId"`
}
func notify(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
  var data Data
  err := decoder.Decode(&data)
  if err != nil {
    glog.Errorf("Failed to decode the request json %s \n", err.Error())
    return
  }
  ...
}
```

If I Do curl command it works without complaining:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST --data '{"namespace": "default", "containerId": "2f7c58d399f2dc35fa1be2abea19301c8e74973ddd72f55a778babf01db5ac26"}' http://mysvc:8080/notify
```

but if I do the same thing with `Python` it complains:

```
jsonPrep['containerId'] = "2f7c58d399f2dc35fa1be2abea19301c8e74973ddd72f55a778babf01db5ac26"
jsonPrep['namespace'] = "default" 
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post('http://mysvc:8080/notify', json=json.dumps(jsonPrep), headers=headers)
```

the `go server` complains :

```
E1026 15:49:48.974117       1 main.go:59] Failed to decode the request json json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type main.Data
```

I don't see what is different when I do `curl` vs rest query in `python`.

Can anyone help me identify the issue?

Comment: In this given instance, printing out the raw `Request.Body` probably would have given you the insight needed to solve the problem. Just a thought for the future, especially given `json` decoding is involved. Very useful to verify what you are decoding is actually valid JSON. Ran into this problem once when an external API returned invalid JSON that I had to fix before decoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `json` argument to `requests.post()` is for passing a value that has not had `json.dumps()` called on it yet.  `requests` calls `json.dumps()` on the `json` argument itself, so because you're passing `json=json.dumps(jsonPrep)`, `jsonPrep` will end up being JSONified twice, which is not what you want.

Either use `data`:

```
requests.post(..., data=json.dumps(jsonPrep), ...)
```

or get rid of the `json.dumps()`:

```
requests.post(..., json=jsonPrep, ...)
```